# ERROR discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready

Tags: python, discord, attributes

I got this error message. Please help me to fix this.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtYGz.png)

### Here's my code:

```
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
def get_latest_article():
    url = 'https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    article = soup.find('div', {'class': 'featured-post'}).find('a')
    title = article.text.strip()
    url = article['href']
    return title, url
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    title, url = get_latest_article()
    await channel.send(f'**{title}**\n{url}')
client.run('bot_token_here')
```

I am trying to create a discord bot that will send messages from https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire to my specific discord channel.

Comment: Hi Abdullah Tahir. Please add your error as a text fragment and not as a screenshot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what it says - `NoneType` doesn't have a `find` attribute. It's pointing to the line that the error occurred on;

`article = soup.find('div', {'class': 'featured-post'}).find('a')`

So either `soup` is `None`, or the first find returns `None`. A useful debugging tip would have been to split that line in to two so you could identify the problem by yourself:

```py
featured_post_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'featured-post'})
article = featured_post_div.find('a')
```

Then you know if `soup` is None or if `featured_post_div` is None.

But clearly, it's the latter. `soup.find('div', {'class': 'featured-post'})` is returning None and not finding anything so obviously the second find will fail. This means that there's no a div element with that classname on that website. You are going to have to go back to the website and use inspect/other tools to find the elements you want and their defining attributes and try again.